# Как заменить основной цвет в изображении?

Tags: python, изображения, цвета

Имеется растровое изображение png. Это схематичное изображение, в которой основной цвет - голубой

Все цвета находятся в примерно таком диапазоне:

`R_range = range(44, 123)
G_range = range(87, 151)
B_range = range(122, 175)`

"Основной цвет" - самый темный, 44,87,122.

Мне необходимо сделать так чтобы градиент остался, но "основной цвет" стал бы (173, 0, 30)

Как такое можно сделать? Были мысли просто вычитать разницу (173-44, 0-151, 30-175), но цвета явно не так работают)

Так же пробовал [RGB_transform](https://gist.github.com/WChargin/d8eb0cbafc4d4479d004) предварительно превратив основное изображение в greyscale, но на выходе получаются совсем иные цвета

Comment: неплохо было бы прикрепить к вопросу пример изображения и результат, который вы хотите получить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких целей лучше использовать не RGB, а HSL. Он позволяет задавать "смещение" цвета, не меняя оттенок. Или наоборот, менять яркость, не меняя основной цвет. В RGB такого добится довольно сложно.

Вот нагуглил один сниппет для конвертации между форматами, надеюсь поможет: https://gist.github.com/mathebox/e0805f72e7db3269ec22

Comment: по-моему, лучше воспользоваться классическими модулями (например [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html))